# Grignard-type reaction of 3-bromocyclohexene, or rather recombination?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, grignard-reagent

I have a question regarding a proposed Grignard-type reaction which involves the conversion of 3-bromocyclohexene to 1-(cyclohex-2-en-1-yl)propan-1-ol, in diethylether. As the bromine atom lies in allyl position to the double bond, it should form the [1,1'-bi(cyclohexane)]-2,2'-diene, instead of the alcohol, shouldn't it? See below:

[image]

Comment: Allyl Magnesium Bromide is commercially available in ethereal solution https://www.fishersci.co.uk/shop/products/allylmagnesium-bromide-1m-solution-diethyl-ether-acroseal-acros-organics-2/p-3771057. It does all the usual Grignard reactions and does not dimerise. I see no reason why the cyclohexenyl analogue should be any different.

Comment: Some preparations of allyl magnesium bromide suggest lower temperatures while others suggest 30 mesh magnesium over the traditional magnesium turnings The 30 mesh increases the surface area of the Mg to maximize Grignard formation over coupling to form 1,5-hexadiene.

Comment: The dimerization under Grignard conditions is described here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S004040200700316X

Comment: I am completely ignorant as to why an allylic halide should be more susceptible to coupling with Grignard than a normal alkyl halide (which generally doesn't couple). Is it because the allylic halide is more reactive to substitution reactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so much organic chemistry the answer is it depends.

As I said in the comments you can buy Allyl Grignard in ether solution, but you can also dimerise it by allowing it to reach room temperature [Organic Syntheses prep here](http://orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV3P0121).

Assuming the cyclohexenyl Grignard behaves similarly (and I think it will) then you can get the expected Grignard addition product with propanal if you add you bromide to the magnesium suspension slowly, keep the Grignard solution cold and add the aldehyde promptly (basically using standard conditions). Let reach rt and take a long lunch break before adding the aldehyde and you will get dimer.

Comment: My understanding is that dimerization occurs during Grignard formation. As bromide is added to the pot, it either reacts with already formed reagent to give dimer or with Mg to give more Grignard. Dimerization would be more prevalent later in the addition rather than in the early stages of addition. Your Org. Syn. link uses rapid addition of allyl chloride which, intentionally,  maximizes biallyl formation.  How does a long lunch break after the reagent is formed lead to dimer? ;)

Comment: I was under the impression that the dimerisation is a slow process that occurs at higher temperatures. You may be correct.

Comment: Dimerization of the Grignard reagent would require an oxidation.

Comment: There is no obvious oxidant present which leads me to ask is this actual dimerisation or nucleophilic displacement of Cl- by allyl anion?

Comment: Exactly! Not a true dimerization. Because the halide is a good electrophile, substitution competes with Grignard formation unless steps are taken to minimize substitution.

Comment: So likely to be somewhat less favoured in the cyclohexenyl case due to steric factors.

Comment: See my link in the Comment to the OP for the cyclohexenyl coupling.

Comment: Can only see the abstract, the rest is behind a paywall

Comment: I just came across this paper. Allegedly solves the coupling problem. https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00397919209409258?needAccess=true

Comment: @user55119  Paywalled again. I know Keith Jones too